# Spacing too tight between rows of a longtable, revtex4.1 document class

Tags: longtable, revtex

I am writing the supplemental material of a paper using the `revtex4-1` document class, and I would like to include a long table of numbers that takes more than a page.

I read the ReVTeX manual and they advise to use the option [H] or the longtable environment. The first option does not work. The second produces a table which has an extremely tight spacing between rows, making the table very hard to read. In addition to this, in the twocolumn mode also the order of appearance of this table and a previous one is switched. I enclose a small file that reproduces the problem (at least in my system, compiling with pdflatex). I will really appreciate any clue on this.

Regards, Curro

File output

[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wuswg.png)

```
\documentclass[aps,prl,a4,preprint]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{longtable}

%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\title{Supplementary Material:\\XXXXX}
\author{LF}
\affiliation{Dipartimento di Fisica} 


\maketitle
We try and collect in the present Supplementary Material section, additional details about technical aspects of the algebraic formalism (such as matrix elements) that are necessary to reproduce our calculations and we give further information on the fitting procedure.

\section*{Supplementary material}


\begin{table*}
\caption{Residuals for fits $F_0$ and $F_1$.\label{tab_residuals}}
\begin{ruledtabular}
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c||c|c|c|c|c}
  Initial &      Final  &  Exp.  &  Calc.\ $F_0$ & Calc.\ $F_1$&Initial &      Final  &  Exp.  &  Calc.\ $F_0$ & Calc.\ $F_1$\\
\hline
0 1 0 0 1 & 2 0 0 0 0 &  128.6& -2.42&  -2.16 & 0 1 2 0 1 & 1 1 1 1 1 & 44.4& -0.76&  -1.96\\
\end{tabular}
\end{ruledtabular}
\end{table*}

\begin{center}
\begin{longtable*}{crc|crc|crc}
\caption[Calculated energy levels]{Calculated energy levels}
\label{tab_calcs}\\

\hline 
$v$ & Calc.  & $|C_{v}|^2$ &$v$ & Calc.  & $|C_{v}|^2$ &$v$ & Calc.  & $|C_{v}|^2$ \\
\hline 
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{9}{c}%
{{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}} \\
\hline 
$v$ & Calc.  & $|C_{v}|^2$ &$v$ & Calc.  & $|C_{v}|^2$ &$v$ & Calc.  & $|C_{v}|^2$ \\
\hline
\endhead

\hline \multicolumn{9}{|r|}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \hline
\endfoot

\hline \hline
\endlastfoot

0 &   0.00000 & 1.00000 &  1 & 440.3463 & 1.00000 &    2 &829.6073 & 0.99660\\   
001 & 16.44050 & 1.00000 &  222 & 452.27921 & 0.99876 &    222 & 373.31953 & 0.99979\\   

\end{longtable*}
\end{center}



\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution, which I do not fully understand: the `cellspace` package allows to define  minimal vertical padding around cells, but does not define any minimal value by itself  and the relevant column specifier have to be prefixed with the letter `S` (or `C` if one uses the `siunitx` package). Now, with `revtex`, it is enough to load the package to obtain a correct vertical spacing. As far as I know, `revtex` does *not* load `cellspace`…

Furthermore, I took the liberty to use `siunitx` for the long table, to have a correct alignment of numbers in their columns:

```
\documentclass[aps,prl,a4,preprint]{revtex4-1}%
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{siunitx} \sisetup{table-format=1.5,table-number-alignment=center}
\newcolumntype{T}{S[table-format=3.5]}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{cellspace}%

%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\title{Supplementary Material:\\XXXXX}
\author{LF}
\affiliation{Dipartimento di Fisica}


\maketitle
We try and collect in the present Supplementary Material section, additional details about technical aspects of the algebraic formalism (such as matrix elements) that are necessary to reproduce our calculations and we give further information on the fitting procedure.

\section*{Supplementary material}


\begin{table*}
  \caption{Residuals for fits $F₀$ and $F₁$.\label{tab_residuals}}
  \begin{ruledtabular}
    \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c||c|c|c|c|c}
      Initial & Final & Exp. & Calc.\ $F₀$ & Calc.\ $F₁$ & Initial & Final & Exp. & Calc.\ $F₀$ & Calc.\ $F₁$ \\
      \hline
      0 1 0 0 1 & 2 0 0 0 0 & 128.6 & $ -2.42 $ & $ -2.16 $ & 0 1 2 0 1 & 1 1 1 1 1 & 44.4 & $ -0.76 $ & $ -1.96 $ \\
    \end{tabular}
  \end{ruledtabular}
\end{table*}

\begin{center}
\setlength\tabcolsep{6pt}
  \begin{longtable}{cTS|cTS|cTS}
    \caption[Calculated energy levels]{Calculated energy levels}
    \label{tab_calcs}\\
    \hline
    $v$ & { (Calc.)} & {$|C_{v}|²$} & $v$ & {Calc.} & {$|C_{v}|²$} & $v$ & {Calc.} & {$|C_{v}|²$} \\
    \hline
    \endfirsthead
    \multicolumn{9}{c}%
    {{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}} \\
    \hline
    $v$ & { Calc.} & {$|C_{v}|²$} & $v$ & { Calc.} & {$|C_{v}|²$} & $v$ & {Calc.} & {$|C_{v}|²$} \\
    \hline
    \endhead
    \hline \multicolumn{9}{|r|}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \hline
    \endfoot
    \hline \hline
    \endlastfoot
    0 & 0.00000 & 1.00000 & 1 & 440.3463 & 1.00000 & 2 & 829.6073 & 0.99660 \\
    001 & 16.44050 & 1.00000 & 222 & 452.27921 & 0.99876 & 222 & 373.31953 & 0.99979 \\
  \end{longtable}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I suggest another layout, without vertical lines. Unfortunately, `booktabs` does not seem to work with `revtex` so I had to emulate its variable thickness lines with the small `boldline` package. I also suggest to change the value of `\tabcolsep` and, for shorter tables with two parts (like table I) to insert some separator (a grey rectangle, here):

```
\documentclass[aps,prl,a4,preprint]{revtex4-1}%
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor} \usepackage{siunitx} \sisetup{table-format=1.5,table-number-alignment=center}
\newcolumntype{T}{S[table-format=3.5]}
\usepackage{longtable, booktabs, boldline}
\usepackage{cellspace}%
%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\title{Supplementary Material:\\XXXXX}
\author{LF}
\affiliation{Dipartimento di Fisica}


\maketitle
We try and collect in the present Supplementary Material section, additional details about technical aspects of the algebraic formalism (such as matrix elements) that are necessary to reproduce our calculations and we give further information on the fitting procedure.

\section*{Supplementary material}


\begin{table*}
  \caption{Residuals for fits $F₀$ and $F₁$.\label{tab_residuals}}\medskip
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
  \begin{ruledtabular}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}*{5}{c} >{\color{lightgray!30}\vrule width12pt}c*{5}{c}@{}}
      Initial & Final & Exp. & Calc.\ $F₀$ & Calc.\ $F₁$ & & Initial & Final & Exp. & Calc.\ $F₀$ & Calc.\ $F₁$ \\
\cline{1-5}\cline{7-11}
      0 1 0 0 1 & 2 0 0 0 0 & 128.6 & $ -2.42 $ & $ -2.16 $& & 0 1 2 0 1 & 1 1 1 1 1 & 44.4 & $ -0.76 $ & $ -1.96 $ \\
    \end{tabular}
  \end{ruledtabular}
\end{table*}

\begin{center}
\setlength\tabcolsep{6pt}
  \begin{longtable}{cTS >{\qquad}ccTS >{\qquad}ccTS}
    \caption[Calculated energy levels]{Calculated energy levels}
    \label{tab_calcs}\\
    \hlineB{2}
    $v$ & { (Calc.)} & {$|C_{v}|²$} & & $v$ & {Calc.} & {$|C_{v}|²$} & & $v$ & {Calc.} & {$|C_{v}|²$} \\
    \cline{1-3} \cline{5-7} \cline{9-11}
    \endfirsthead
    \multicolumn{9}{c}%
    {{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}} \\
    \hline
    $v$ & { Calc.} & {$|C_{v}|²$} & & $v$ & { Calc.} & {$|C_{v}|²$} & & $v$ & {Calc.} & {$|C_{v}|²$} \\
    \hline
    \endhead
    \hline \multicolumn{9}{|r|}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \hline
    \endfoot
     \hlineB{2}
    \endlastfoot
    0 & 0.00000 & 1.00000 & & 1 & 440.3463 & 1.00000 & & 2 & 829.6073 & 0.99660 \\
    001 & 16.44050 & 1.00000 & & 222 & 452.27921 & 0.99876 & & 222 & 373.31953 & 0.99979 \\
  \end{longtable}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The appearance now has greatly improved. Thanks for the tip. Still the interplay between the longtable and the regular table is not perfect but the solution provided is great.

Comment: @Currix: I've added another layout, without vertical lines, which looks more professional, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

The revtex4-1 document class modifies some of LaTeX's low-level table-generating parameters. The following suggestion isn't a complete remedy, but it should work fairly well. First, load the `array` package in the preamble. Second, issue the instruction `\setlength{\extrarowheight}{-3pt}` immediately *before* `\begin{longtable}`.

Since `longtable` environments are automatically centered, do remove the `center` environment that currently encases the `longtable` environment.